# how to download xamarin for visual studio2015 update2 in China

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I want to download Xamarin for visual studio 2015 !
I clicked download button but it didn't run. What should I do? I am taking a major in Software Engineering **from china**.

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: please show us what you have

Comment: no After I clicked download button,nothing happended I wait long time

Comment: I didn't have xamarin acount!what do I need to download xamarin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things can be happening:

- China blocked your access to such content. It is not new that the chinese government blocks legit content from their users if it does not suit them. Are you being blocked? To find out, open the link with Google Chrome, press F12, change to the Networks tab, and try to download. The output should let you know.
- Your input is incorrect. Admitedly, the page validation is terrible. They try to validate your name, as if there were a list of names that people should use ... If no request is sent to their servers, it is because you are failing the validation. Check your name, email and company fields. This is what I used:

  - Name: John Doe
  - Email: johndoe@mailinator.com
  - Company: none
  - Check all 3 checkboxes (set to true)

You can use this information **as is** to try and download xamarin, *it worked for me*.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you very much With your help I download success

Comment: OK thanks! Please mark this question as an answer so other people can use it too!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Update 2 link : http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/7/4/77471e13-cfac-43c2-b76e-459238142bd5/vs2015.2.com_fra.iso

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simply that Xamarin downloads as well as Google Android bits (part of the dependencies) are blocked by the Great Firewall of China if you are not familiar with that fact.

Make sure that you use a VPN connection to connect, or you won't be able to try it out right now.